# Geometry Proximity and Raycast Nodes not working during animation

Tags: geometry-nodes

The nodes work fine if I'm in a stil frame and I change the location of the target object, but if this object is animated the attributes "freeze".

This is the geo nodes set up:

[image]

The "freezed" during time spreadsheet:

[image]

And the geometry set up (position of Suzanne changing over time):

[image]

Blender File here:

[image]